# Need help in one issue while Cake php migration from 1.3 to 2.x

Tags: cakephp

Hi We are trying to migrate our website which is currently running with Cakephp 1.3 so we are first trying to migrate it Cakephp 2.X than after will try for cake3.x

So I am facing problem we have some values which we are using as a global variable & in cakephp 1.3 we have defined these in app/config/config.php like

```
$config['Site.title']    =  'XXXXXX';

$siteFolder   = dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))); 

define('SITE_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $siteFolder);
define('MENTORS_IMAGE_PATH','members'.DS.'profile_images');
```

But now when we are migrating so in new version no config file under Config folder according to new structure & if I am copy pasting same file under Config folder that also not solving my problem giving error message:-

> Use of undefined constant SITE_URL - assumed 'SITE_URL'

Comment: [The migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html) is required reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP 2 you should define constants in app/Config/bootstrap.php. The error message you are getting is probably because CakePHP doesn't know about your config.php file. If you want to keep these in that file just `require` it from within bootstrap.php:-

```
require 'config.php';
```

In CakePHP you should be defining constants/configuration settings using `Configure::write()` and reading them using `Configure::read()`. For example:-

```
Configure::write('Site.title', 'XXXXX');
```

Comment: Thanks @drmonkeyninja I have tried solution- require 'config.php'; its working for me.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has helped please accept it as the correct answer to help others with a similar problem. :-)